# On the proof of localization in symplectic geometry

Tags: differential-forms, group-actions, symplectic-geometry

I was working on the proof of Duistermaat-Heckman theorem in *Introduction to Symplectic Topology* by Dusa McDuff. He used a lemma called localization. It can be found on page 194.  You can find 
[the lemma and the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0sei.png) here.

and here is the [definition of the differential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Tu3.png)

I have some questions about this proof.

1.What dose it mean to "average a form over certain group action"?

2.Why is $\phi^{*} \tau-\tau$ exact?

3.Why dose the first part of the proof work for $\phi^{*} \tau$? I cant seem to find the needed one-form here in the first part.

Forgive me for these stupid questions. Any comment or answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Averaging a form $\alpha$ (or anything really) on a manifold $M$ over a compact Lie group $G$ acting on it means to take $\int_G \phi_g^*\alpha dg$ (where $\phi_g$ is the multiplication by $g$ map, and $dg$ is the invariant measure on $G$).
2. $\phi^*\tau-\tau$ is exact because $\phi$ is isotopic to the identity, so it must induce the identity map on cohomology.
3. The point is that $\phi^*\tau$ vanishes in a neighborhood of the fixed point set, so you can find $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(X)=1$ away from such a neighborhood, then the same argument should work.